# Visual Studio Moc'ing headers after source

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio 2013, qt 4.7

We recently noticed that some new functionality wasn't present in a release build of our project. It turned out that the header files in the project are being moc'd **after** the source is compiled and the executable generated, e.g. the build log looks like this:

```
>  Using cl
2>  app.cpp
2>  newDialog.cpp
2>  moc_newDialog.cpp
2>  Generating Code...
2>  viewer.vcxproj -> PATHTOBUILDLOCATION\output\x86_Debug\\viewer.exe
```

**and then**

```
2>  Moc'ing newDialog.h...
2>          1 file(s) copied.
```

We are using the qt add-in for visual studio to generate the moc commands for the headers automatically; as per all other projects, but we haven't noticed this before. 
Is there a way to force the headers to be moc'd earlier?

Comment: Qt's moc tool should be invoked **before** the build starts. Check where it's configured. Is it in your project's pre-build or post-build event?

Comment: In visual studio, moc is invoked on a per-file basis, as a custom build setting  on each header. It seems there should be a way to force these to be processed before the build, but I can't see it!

Comment: I know, but where the post build activity comes from? It appears, as you said, after your viewer.exe application is built.

Comment: I wish I knew! There's nothing set up for post-build apart from copying the built executable to another directory.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found the cause of this. Somehow (we don't know how or why), there is a line for each configuration in the project file thus:

```
<CustomBuildAfterTargets>Build</CustomBuildAfterTargets>
```

which was causing the problem. Deleting this has resolved the issue. If anyone knows how this might have been set in via visual studio, please comment!